# VS Code: Injection grammar scope for custom keyword is overriden in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I want to make a small VS Code extension to add syntax highlighting to a handful of custom keywords in C/C++ code.

I am trying to do that with an injection grammar into the `source.c` and `source.cpp` language scopes, following the [VS Code syntax highlighting guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars).  Per the guide, prefixing the injection selector scope with `L:` means that "[the] injected grammar's rules will be applied before any existing grammar rules".  This seems to work fine with C code, but in C++ it some (but not all) grammar rules override my injected grammar.

For a MWE, suppose I want to add a `par_for` keyword for parallel loops.

I define the extension in `package.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "contributes": {
        "grammars": [{
            "scopeName": "parfor.injection",
            "path": "./syntaxes/parfor.injection.json",
            "injectTo": ["source.c", "source.cpp"]
        }]
    }
}
```

and the injected grammar in `syntaxes/parfor.injection.json` to apply my new scope `keyword.control.parfor` to all instances of `par_for` (except in strings and comments):

```json
{
    "scopeName": "parfor.injection",
    "injectionSelector": [
        "L:source.c -string -comment",
        "L:source.cpp -string -comment"
    ],
    "patterns": [
        { "include": "#parfor-keyword" }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "parfor-keyword": {
            "name": "keyword.control.parfor",
            "match": "\\bpar_for\\b"
        }
    }
}
```

In C, things work as expected:
[image: par_for highlighting in C: correct]

But in C++, `par_for` gets treated like a function name:
[image: par_for highlighting in C++: wrong]

The screenshots were taken from a VS Code testing instance with all extensions disabled.

The issue in C++ is apparently triggered by the parenthesis following `par_for`; if I write, say, `par_for foo`, then the `keyword.control.parfor` scope is applied to `par_for` as expected.

Is there a way to ensure my injected grammar pattern takes precedence over whatever the C++ grammar is doing?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, only my additions are simpler: Byte, Word16, etc. I tried to follow your example, but there is no syntaxes/ directory in which I would create Byte.injection.json on my install (under ~/.vscode. Could you provide full path names and more context for your file additions? Where would Byte.injection.json file be located?  Any help appreciated. Did you ever have success with your issue?

Comment: I used your injectionSelector, thanks!